# overflow? cannot find source, strange

Tags: c, struct, overflow

i have the following two structs within my project

```
typedef volatile struct {
  unsigned char rx_buf[MAX_UART_BUF];   //Input buffer over UART
  uint8_t rx_flag;                  //Indicates received data over UART
  uint8_t rx_length;                    //length of the input buffer
} UART;

UART *gUART;

typedef volatile struct {
  unsigned int target_s[NR_BLDC];       //Target Position in Signals
  int distance_s[NR_BLDC];          //Distance between gActual_s[NR_BLDC] and gTarget_s
  unsigned int old_s[NR_BLDC];      //Position before starting to new destination
  unsigned int ramp_s[NR_BLDC];     //Duration of ramp(accelerate/decelerate) in Signals
  unsigned int count_dt[NR_BLDC];       //Actual nr of PWM ISR timer calls
  uint8_t dc_max[NR_BLDC];          //Maximal Duty Cycle set to reach the destination
} POSITIONING;

POSITIONING *gPOS;
```

when i write to rx_flag or rx_length within *gUART it somehow changes the content of distance_s[0] within the *gPOS struct(error occures when executing one of the two lines in the code section below). i is of type uint8_t and within limits.

```
            gUART->rx_length = i;                       //set receive byte length
            gUART->rx_flag = 1;                         //Indicate that data ready for use
```

I have no clue how this can happen, since even if it is an overflow the two structs are at lest separated by multiple bytes within the bss section.

Any tricks/ideas how to find the error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You do ***initialize*** `gUART` somewhere?

Comment: You have probably freed the object before and the space was reallocated to another object.

Comment: This are Static variables and should therefore be initialized to zero by default, right? Anyway i don't read the uninitialized variables and it would not explain the behaviour

Comment: Have you allocated memory for *gUART? You should not directly write values to pointers like this: gUART->rx_length = i;

Comment: what is the right way to write to an value within the struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't show more code, I'll have to make two assumptions: That variables with the prefix `g` are global, and that you don't initialize those pointer (i.e. make them point anywhere).

Uninitialized global variables are *zero initialized* by the compiler. For pointers that means that they are initialized to `NULL`, meaning both pointers are pointing to `NULL`. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In your specific case you're very lucky the whole application don't crash and burn, and more specifically since both pointers are pointing to `NULL` they are both pointing to the same memory meaning that changing one structure will change both.

Either you need to actually make the pointers point somewhere, or not declare them as pointers at all.